# How to get all USA timezone IDs using nodatime

Tags: c#, nodatime

How to get all USA timezone IDs using nodatime?

https://nodatime.org/TimeZones

Above page lists all timezone ids in nodatime,
is there any API to get all USA timezone IDs?

Comment: Get all and filter by contry code `US`?

Answer (score 2):

found api:

```
public static List<TzdbZoneLocation> GetAllTimeZones()
{
    return TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default
                .ZoneLocations
                .Where(x => x.CountryCode == "US")
                .ToList();
}
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/jrolstad/5ca7d78dbfe182d7c1be